# How to use a Character to print an array in Fortran

Tags: fortran

If I have some real vectors, say `vector_a`, `vector_b`, `vector_c`, ...`vector_n`, how can I use a character input (for example `'vector_a'`) for writing the real `vector_a`?

This is an example:

```
 DOUBLE PRECISION :: g_xx( Nx, Ny, Nz ), g_xy( Nx, Ny, Nz ), g_xz( Nx, Ny, Nz ) 

 CHARACTER *10 :: g_ij

 g_ij = 'g_xx'

 PRINT*, MAXVAL( g_ij )
```

The last row is clearly wrong, because MAXVAL don't take in input a character.

How can I do?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Also, please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. I do not really understand what you are asking. You want to access a Fortran variable by its name stored in a character string? That is not possible and we have some existing questions and answers about that.

Comment: Yes, I want to access to a real vector using the corresponding character string. I searched in old questions but found nothing. Can you link me some threads about that? Thanks you

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268418/interpret-strings-as-variable-names-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226498/fortran-dynamic-variables-names?noredirect=1&lq=1